# Record not being inserted into mySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am running an insert statement from a PHP file and then I run some code to check if the insert worked.  PHP tells me "success".  But when I check my database to see if the record exists, it does not.  Furthermore, when I run the sql statement directly in MySQL administrator, it works fine.  I am quite certain that I am not inserting into the wrong database or table.  Here is a cleaned up version of the code:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO companies (name, source_id, source_site, seeking_cf, currency, i_target, equity_offered, money_raised, num_investors, raised_pct, descr, city, state, country, categories_id, logo) VALUES (\"XYZ Widgets\", \"31\", 22, 1, \"£\", 250000, 0, 0, 0, 0, \"(Business Plan\", \"London\", \"\", \"UK\", 0, \"http://www.website.com/xyz.jpg\")";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);  
  if(mysql_affected_rows($conn) == 0) { 
    $utoh = "fail"; 
  } else { 
    $utoh = "success";      
  }
  echo $utoh;
```

So the result says "Success" but the record is not in the db.
PHP is version 5.3.  MySQL is 5.5.

Comment: Please, use [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Check for an insert id, see if that still passes.  Also, consider NOT using the mysql_ function group as it is deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure your field can handle the `£` you are trying to enter? From memory that isn't a normal character....

Comment: @Fluffeh That's the GBP symbol. It won't break the query, but will probably not be encoded correctly.

Comment: Can you echo out `$sql` and run it right in the database?

Comment: @MattHumphrey I know what it is, I have some in my wallet as well as a Oyster card lol. I was thinking that the query might accept it, but the database might refuse it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I hate to condone using `mysql_`, you should do the error checking on the `mysql_query` statement...

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO companies (name, source_id, source_site, seeking_cf, currency, i_target, equity_offered, money_raised, num_investors, raised_pct, descr, city, state, country, categories_id, logo) VALUES (\"XYZ Widgets\", \"31\", 22, 1, \"£\", 250000, 0, 0, 0, 0, \"(Business Plan\", \"London\", \"\", \"UK\", 0, \"http://www.website.com/xyz.jpg\")";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);  
if (!$rs)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
}
```

We can now see what the error was.

Comment: I guess I thought that my statement ---if(mysql_affected_rows($conn) == 0) { ---   performed the same thing as your ---- if (!$rs) ---.  But I guess not, because this one is evaluating to false where the other is true.

Answer (score 1):

Use `single quotes` instead of double quotes.

Your code is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    // insert one row
    $name = 'one';
    $value = 1;
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with single quotes.

Comment: His quotes are escaped with `\\` characters, so they should be fine?

Comment: Very good point, but doesn't really answer the question.  The issue is the insert doesn't work.

Comment: @Fluffeh you escape with `backslash`? yes they should be fine but for better standard, he can use PDO or MySQLi instead sir.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO companies (name, source_id, source_site, seeking_cf, currency, i_target, equity_offered, money_raised, num_investors, raised_pct, descr, city, state, country, categories_id, logo) VALUES (\"XYZ Widgets\", \"31\", 22, 1, \"£\", 250000, 0, 0, 0, 0, \"(Business Plan\", \"London\", \"\", \"UK\", 0, \"http://www.website.com/xyz.jpg\")";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);  
  if(!$rs) { 
    $utoh = "fail"; 
  } else { 
    $utoh = "success";      
  }
  echo $utoh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try?:

1:

```
  mysql_query("set names utf8;");
    before mysql_query($insert)?
```

2:

change quotes " by ' inside query

Comment: I think Damian is on the right track here.  I tried his suggestion and it didn't work.  But after more debugging I realize that when I cleaned up the code in my original post I took the "descr" data and greatly shortened it.  There is something in that data causing the INSERT to fail because if I set it to "abc" the query runs fine in PHP.  I think I'll look into PDO or mysqli and see what happens.

Comment: I always use phpmyadmin to debug my sql. Just echo out your sql statement in your code and paste it into phpmyadmin. Once in there, you can change your sql until it runs as exected.

Comment: Ok, I may try that.  I don't currently have phpmyadmin installed but I can do so.

Comment: I changed all my code to use mysqli but I still get the error.  It is definitely due to the descr field having weird characters in it.  The descr field is a type "TEXT".  The charset on the table is UTF8.  The collation is utf8_general_ci.  Seems like it should work.